# Memory usage profiled in task manager and memory profiler tools

Tags: winforms, .net

.Net winform application.

I used several memory profiler, including CLR profiler, DotTrace memory, Net memory profiler.
The tools gave the result that the allocated memory was 38-40M. But I found that working set was 300-400M in task manager(almost the same size as Peak working set or memory or commit size.

So what's the difference between the two results? What do the results mean?

Answer (score 0):

those tools may show you private bytes or managed heap size, this does not include, e.g. memory mapped file, either page file backed or disk file backed, your app may be r/w ing
big mapped file, so working set looks big, or your app just load too many dll/assemblies.
VMMAP (from sysinternals) can give a clear overview of memory type/size in your app.

Comment: Thank you. My app do load more than 20 DLLs.