# Memory usage profiled in task manager and ANTS profiler

Tags: .net, silverlight, memory-management, taskmanager, ants

I am optimizing my silverlight application (in/out of browser) -memory optimization

I used several memory profilers, including ANTS, .Net memory profiler. The tools gave the result that the allocated memory was 38-40 MB. But, when I was using task manager the memory was at 300-400MB.

So what's the difference between the two results? What do the results mean?

I do know the same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136239/memory-usage-profiled-in-task-manager-and-memory-profiler-to). I am just searching a better answer from experts.

Answer (score 0):

please use GC.Collect() for release memor,